# Continue track location after app closed

Tags: cordova, geolocation, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I want to track user coordinates to my server every x seconds
I tried some background geolocation plugins such as mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation and cordova-background-geolocation-lt

but when user close app it does not work to track user coordinates

are there any phonegap plugin which still continue track after user close app?

Comment: Yes, `cordova-background-geolocation-lt` if you configure it properly.  Doing so will cause your app to display a persistent notification and this can't be changed.

Comment: @BShaps thanks....I will look it with all details...In my app user don't want to see any notification.In that plugin there is background enabled text with small icon.Can I remove that notification and icon ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to remove that as it is required by android.  Even native apps MUST have that notification in more recent versions of the android OS.